# Bootstrap Carousel MyCarousel.carousel(number)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is a general question, which i cant find the answer too. With twitters bootstrap carousel is it possible to use the `MyCarousel.carousel(number)` function to go to a specific slide, but instead of using a number can it be text. Or does it have to be a number to go directly to the slide.

So instead of naming the slides say 1 to 5 and then using `MyCarousel.carousel(3)` to go to slide three, can it be slides say a to e and then use `MyCarousel.carousel(c)` to go to slide c.

i have tried doing this but i get the following error using text:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'c' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

So is this possible or should i just stick to using numbers? The reason for using text is to make it easier for the user as i am allowing them to input what slide they would like to go to in the url, and using text would make it easier for them.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

It must be a number..

> .carousel(number) - 
>   Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap carousel cycles through the slides based on their numeric index value.  If you would rather use a text based value, you would need to build an array that maps your text based values to the slide numeric index.

This would allow the user to type their selection into some sort of input field and then you can select it through your array mapping.

```js
//Create a distinct key/value array mapping out your slides
var slides = new Array();
slides["first slide"]=0; 
slides["second slide"]=1; 
slides["third slide"]=2;

//Whatever your user inputs and you collect
userInput = "second slide";

//Make sure the input "key" exists first
if(slides.hasOwnProperty(userInput)) {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(slides[userInput]);
} else {
  alert("Sorry, that slide does not exist");
}
```